# Bundle/getArguments() gives NullPtrException

Tags: java, android

I want to pass an `ArrayList` to my fragment from my activity that is accessed through the bottom navigation bar, the bundle returns null when I call `getInt()` or `getParcelableArrayList()`

EDIT: pasted whole files, in hope that will help... + put the bundle in on create(didn't help)

Code:

main activity(where it's sent)

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private boolean isAdsRemoved;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private List<AppListModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private int totalUsage = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!checkForPermission(this)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, CheckForPermissionActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - 86400000;
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        UsageStatsManager usageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService("usagestats");
        List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats = usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, startTime, endTime);

        for (UsageStats us : queryUsageStats) {
            Drawable icon;
            int totalTimeMin = (int) us.getTotalTimeInForeground() / 60000;
            boolean alreadyThere = false;

            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo ai;

            if (us.getPackageName().equals("com.android.systemui")) {
                continue;
            }

            try {
                ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(us.getPackageName(), 0);
                icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(us.getPackageName());
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                ai = null;
                icon = null;
                Log.d(TAG, "Package name not found");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
            if (applicationName.length() > 15) {
                applicationName = applicationName.substring(0, Math.min(applicationName.length(), 13)) + "...";
            }

            //if packages that have the same names, but are registered multiple times, they are merged
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                for (AppListModel item : list) {
                    if (item.getAppName().equals(applicationName)) {
                        item.setTotalTime(totalTimeMin + item.getTotalTime());
                        totalUsage += totalTimeMin;
                        alreadyThere = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (totalTimeMin > 0 && !alreadyThere) {

                if (!applicationName.equals("(unknown)")) {
                    list.add(new AppListModel(applicationName, icon, totalTimeMin));
                }
                Log.d(TAG, us.getPackageName() + " = " + us.getTotalTimeInForeground());
                totalUsage += totalTimeMin;
            }
        }

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("label", 0);

        if (preferences.getBoolean("ad_removed", false)) {
            isAdsRemoved = true;
        }

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        if (preferences.getBoolean("ad_removed", false)) {
            mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (!preferences.getBoolean("ad_removed", false) && !isAdsRemoved) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            isAdsRemoved = intent.getBooleanExtra("ad_removal", false);
        }

        editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("ad_removed", isAdsRemoved).commit();

        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.itemDashboard);

        Fragment dashboard = new FragmentDashboard();

        ArrayList<AppListModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        arrayList.addAll(list);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("totalUsage", totalUsage);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arrayList", arrayList);
        dashboard.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, dashboard).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment selectedFragment = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.itemStats:
                    selectedFragment = new FragmentStats();
                    break;
                case R.id.itemDashboard:
                    selectedFragment = new FragmentDashboard();
                    break;
                case R.id.itemStore:
                    selectedFragment = new FragmentStore();
                    break;
                case R.id.itemSettings:
                    selectedFragment = new FragmentSettings();
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };

    private boolean checkForPermission(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
            return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

FragmentDashboard

```java
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //View itself
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

        //'TIME WASTED' counter
        count = view.findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentText);

        //RecyclerView
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        //Buttons
        showAllBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.showAllButton);
        hideBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.hideAllButton);
        timeNotifBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.timeButton);
        stopLimiterButton = view.findViewById(R.id.disableLimit);

        list = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("arrayList");
        totalUsage = getArguments().getInt("totalUsage", 0);

        int totalUsageHrs = (int) totalUsage / 60;
        int totalUsageMin = (int) totalUsage - totalUsageHrs * 60;

        if (totalUsageHrs == 0) {
            count.setText(totalUsageMin + " minutes");
        } else {
            count.setText(totalUsageHrs + " hours, " + totalUsageMin + " minutes");
        }

        //sorts list in descending order
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<AppListModel>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(AppListModel appListModel, AppListModel t1) {
                return Integer.valueOf(t1.getTotalTime()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(appListModel.getTotalTime()));
            }
        });

        mostUsedApps = list.subList(0, Math.min(list.size(), 3));

        adapter = new RVAdapterDashboard(getActivity());
        adapter.setList(mostUsedApps);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        showAllBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter = new RVAdapterDashboard(getActivity());
                adapter.setList(list);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                showAllBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                hideBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        hideBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                hideBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                adapter = new RVAdapterDashboard(getActivity());
                adapter.setList(mostUsedApps);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                showAllBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hideBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });

        timeNotifBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (totalUsage > 720) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Take a break, you have spent too much on your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    DialogDashboard dialogDashboard = new DialogDashboard();
                    dialogDashboard.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "notif_dialog");
                }
            }
        });

        stopLimiterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isJobServiceOn(getActivity())) {
                    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                    scheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No limit set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dashboard.FragmentDashboard.onCreateView(FragmentDashboard.java:78)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2663)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2613)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:246)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:542)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1395)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7348)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1955)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

EDIT 2, I fixed the problem, I just put the bundle in both `onCreate` and `onMenuItemSelected`

Comment: could you please add some additional details? it is not clear where in the lifecycle of the fragment are you calling the code responsible for getting the data.

Comment: Post your error log, and where you called `Bundle bundle = getArguments();`?

Comment: @mostafa3dmax I'll update the code and post the log error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 case R.id.itemStats:
                 selectedFragment = new FragmentDashboard();
                 ArrayList<AppListModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
                 arrayList.addAll(list);

                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                 bundle.putInt("totalUsage", totalUsage);
                 bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arrayList", arrayList);

                 selectedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                 break;

             case R.id.itemDashboard:
                 selectedFragment = new FragmentDashboard();
                 break;
```

In this part of your code you instantiate `FragmentDashboard` in two case statement which in second one you did not pass any bundle as arguments and because this you get error when you call `getArguments().get...` in it.

Comment: even when I put it in the item dashboard it still gives nullptrexception

Comment: It doesn't make sense ! can you post your FragmentDashboard code?

Comment: I've figured it out, I was supposed to be passing it on create instead of on menu item selected...

Comment: nevermind, putting it in on create didn't fix

Comment: Look ,You have not still putting any arguments in your dashboardFragment in : `case R.id.itemDashboard:selectedFragment = new FragmentDashboard();break;`

Comment: check now I edited the code, so passing it on create isn't enough?

Comment: No it's not. Every time you creating new fragment that needs arguments you must pass bundle to it as arguments

Comment: so I should pass in on create and on menu item selected?

Comment: Yes you should  .

Answer (score 1):

You only set the arguments on your `FragmentStats` instance. Other fragments such as the `FragmentDashboard` seen in the stacktrace don't have arguments set, and `getArguments()` returns null.

If you want the same arguments to be applied to all fragments, move the `Bundle` setup and `setArguments()` after the `switch`-`case`. (And maybe add a `default` case too so `selectedFragment` won't ever be null.)

Comment: oh, I realized, I set it in the wrong fragment, it's supposed to be sent in fragment dashboard...

Comment: weird, it still returns null even if I set it for FragmentDashboard..